# Why the macro works separately and when you merge it with another macro does not work?

Tags: excel, vba

When I execute the macro separately it works, but when I merge with another macro it does not work.

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim z As Integer
    Sheets("transp").Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove   
  For z = 1 To 110
    Sheets("transp").Cells(2, z).Value = "VAR_" & Sheets("transp").Cells(1, z).Value & "_" & Sheets("input").Cells(1, 4).Value
  Next z
    Sheets("transp").Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
End Sub
```

Comment: You should avoid using `Selection` and `.Select` ... However without seeing how you integrate this macro into another one, we can't help you.

Comment: I rewrote the code without using Selection and .Select and it worked. Thank you

Comment: This is one Macro, you would have to be clear about "merge" and what you are doing.